# What does Google analytics api in website?

Tags: web, google-analytics

I want to get idea about what means "Integration Google analytics api with website".
What does google analytics api do?
Please give me answer.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

*Notice I removed the word API from your first question.  The API is not part of the website.   Its two different things.*

> I want to get idea about what means "Integration Google analytics with website"

Adding the [Google analytics JS snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) tells your website to send statistic information to the Google Analytics servers through the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en).   The snippet just sends information about the current page being viewed and non specific information about the user viewing it.  (location of the user, system language, Page being view ....).   Once the data is sent to [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) the data is then analyzed so that Google can present you with some nice reports of your sites statistics.

> What does [google analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) do?

The Google Analytics API allows you to extract the data stored in Google Analytics out.  So that instead of viewing it on [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) you can use the data in other systems.  Example: In my case we extract the data from Google Analytics and store it in our existing Business intelligence data-ware house.